# How do you get the gear in the overworld?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

[image]

I've acquired two of the three years I need from Gerudo Village but still need a third. This one in particular is taunting me… I see a relatively easy solution using hover boots, but I can't find any. I've got the hookshot, the power gauntlets, the feather, etc., but this year still eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the solution. Given the limitations of the switch for now the answer only lives as [this tweet](https://twitter.com/bp_switch/status/1182330164392292353?s=19), but all you have to do is:

- Use the non breakable block to get onto the pile of sand
- Place the non breakable block next to the gear
- Move to two tiles away from the breakable block (see diagram)
- Move right so you're facing the block
- Use the feather to jump onto the block
- Move up to collect the gear

```
 . . *     * gear
 @ : O     O non breakable block on sand mound
 : : .     : sand mound
 o . .     o breakable rock on ground
           . ground
           @ you on sand mound
```